# Как реализовать сдвигание пунктов ListView в обе стороны

Tags: android, listview, swipe

Как воплотить сдвигание пунктов списка со следующими особенностями:

1) Чтобы каждый пункт мог сдвигаться как вправо, так и влево

2) При сдвигании открывающиеся фоновые панели задерживались в сдвинутом состоянии

3) Открывающиеся панели могли содержать кликабельные View-элементы

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Наиболее популярные библиотеки к сожалению не соответствуют этим требованиям:

https://github.com/baoyongzhang/SwipeMenuListView - можно сдвигать только в одну сторону

https://github.com/wdullaer/SwipeActionAdapter - сдвигать можно в обе стороны, но при сдвигании панели не задерживаются, а сразу же закрываются. То есть сдвигание панелей призвано само по себе вызывать обработчик, а не показать дополнительные интерактивные элементы

https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidSwipeLayout - одновременная возможность сдвигания как вправо так и влево отсутствует - нужно заранее определить, куда Вы хотите сдвигать

Comment: https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidSwipeLayout , https://github.com/chthai64/SwipeRevealLayout

Comment: @pavlofff в обоих примерах одновременно можно сдвигать только в одну сторону, предварительно указав - в какую